# Dash dataTable conditional cell formatting isn't working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to [change a color of a cell of a Dash dataTable](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/style) based on a value. I have tried a minimal example:

```
            html.Div(
            children=[
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='table_1',
                    data=df.to_dict('records'),
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                    #conditional cell formating
                    style_data_conditional=[
                        {
                            'if': {
                                'column_id': 'col1',
                                'filter': 'col1 > num(15)'
                            },
                            'backgroundColor': '#3D9970',
                            'color': 'white',
                        },
                    ],
                    n_fixed_rows=2,
                    filtering=True,
                    sorting=True,
                    sorting_type="multi"
                )],
        )
```

After adding the style_conditional, the table is not showing at all, and there is no error message thrown. The table is embedded in html component, and after looking into forums and on github, I am stiil not sure if I have missed anything here, and if I need to write a callback for this. The example provided in the mentioned [tutorial](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/style) is not suggesting the need for a callback.

Update:

Tried to run minimal version with the same code and different data, with same results, that is no change in cell colors. My libraries are up to date, but something in the environment may still be causing problems.

Full code:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

# Having trouble with conditional when column name has spaces
df = df.rename({'Number of Solar Plants': 'Plants'}, axis='columns')
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=[{
        "if": {'column_id': 'State',
               'filter': 'State eq "Nevada"'
               },
        "backgroundColor": "#3D9970",
        "color": "white"
    }],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it was back in 2019, but with recent releases of *Dash Datatables*:

1. Column names in filter expressions must be wrapped in curly braces
2. `filter` has been renamed to `filter_query`

```py
style_data_conditional=[{
    "if": {
        'column_id': 'State',
        'filter_query': '{State} eq "Nevada"'
        #                ^     ^ <-- required braces
    },
    "backgroundColor": "#3D9970",
    "color": "white"
}]
```

BTW: You can conveniently highlight the entire row by removing the `column_id` line.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you will need a callback for this like said in the tutorial. According to the last example of the tutorial I think you have a typo (one ' to much).

Change this line

```
'filter': 'col1' > num(15)'
```

to:

```
'filter': 'col1 > num(15)'
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll edit my questions, it's a typo here, and the code was as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and i found that giving the index directly rather than a condition was a lot easier.

```
style_data_conditional = [{'if': {'column_id': 'col1',"row_index": x},'backgroundColor': '#3D9970','color': 'white'} for x in df[df['col1']>15].index ]
```

it's ugly as it has been hard coded but it did the trick for me when the direct filter did not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it did not work for me, since the dataset is dynamically populated and changes frequently.

Comment: well every time you change the data set, it generates  an event, a callback updating the style_data_conditionnal would be a fix (sub optimal tho). i have not found any way to do it otherwise as of now.